# Printing Linked List - C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've got a basic question. int storage[] = {8,6,4,2}. Why does this print 2 4 6 8 but not 8 6 4 2? Can you please explain why? Which part of the code causes it? I couldn't understand.

Here is the code:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <ctime>

     using namespace std;

  struct node {
int info;
node *next; 

node::node ()
{}

node::node (const int & s, node * link)
    : info(s), next (link)
{}
    };

    void DisplayList (node * head)
   {
cout << "The list content is: ";
node * ptr = head;
   while (ptr != NULL) 
{
    cout << ptr ->info << " ";
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
cout << endl<<endl;
      }

 int main()
  {
int storage[] = {8,6,4,2};
node *head = NULL;
node *temp = NULL;

for (int k=0; k < 4; k++)  {
    temp = new node();
    temp->info = storage[k];
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}

DisplayList (head);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why not just step through the code in your debugger ? You'll learn a lot more that way...

Comment: I don't even know how to debug. I'm just a beginner coder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
int storage[] = {8,6,4,2};
node *head = NULL;
node *temp = NULL;

for (int k=0; k < 4; k++)  {
    temp = new node();
    temp->info = storage[k];
    temp->next = head;        // <----- here, temp is before head
    head = temp;              //        head is made first node again
}
```

prepends each element *before* `head`, as it is processed in order, in `{8,6,4,2}`. Thus you create the list in reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

Your `head` is getting overwritten by every new node you create and thus your for loop is appending in reverse order

This is what you want..

```
for (int k=0; k < 4; k++) 
{
    temp = new node();
    temp->info = storage[k];
    temp->next=NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
        head=temp;
    else
        head->next=temp; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you start filling from the other end of storage, or you can do this:

```
int storage[] = {8,6,4,2};
node *head = NULL;
node *temp = NULL;
node *previous = NULL;

for (int k=0; k < 4; k++)  {
    temp = new node();
    if (head == NULL)
    {
       head = temp;
    }
    if (previous != NULL)
    {
       previous->next = temp;
    }
    temp->info = storage[k];
    previous = temp;
}
```